# Trying to import firebase config into my vue file

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

Edit: error added ^^
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QGRx.png

```
firebase.js?5b23:11 Uncaught TypeError: app.database is not a function
at eval (firebase.js?5b23:11)
at Object../src/components/firebase/firebase.js (app.js:3496)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
at fn (app.js:89)
at eval (selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/front-end/Getstarted.vue:3)
at Object../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/front-end/Getstarted.vue (app.js:2791)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
at fn (app.js:89)
at eval (Getstarted.vue?5f4d:1)
at Object../src/components/front-end/Getstarted.vue (app.js:3552)
```

So i'm trying to put the firebase code in a different file other then the .vue file i use it in. It does work like supposed to if i put it in the vue file so no problems there. However i can't seem to figure out on how to do that correctly.

```
<script>
import Firebase, { functions } from 'firebase'
import conf from '../firebase/firebase'

let config = {
    apiKey: ''
    authDomain: ''
    databaseURL: ''
    projectId: ''
    storageBucket: ''
    messagingSenderId: ''
}

let app = Firebase.initializeApp(config)
let db = app.database()

let booksRef = db.ref('books')
(dashboard.Vue)
```

***this is how it is in my vue file ***

I have 2 javascript files
One with:

```
import config from './firebaseConfig'

class Firebase {
  constructor () {
    firebase.initializeApp(config)
  }
}

let db = app.database()

let booksRef = db.ref('books')

export default Firebase()
(firebase.js)
```

and one with:

```
let config = {
  apiKey: '',
  authDomain: '',
  databaseURL: '',
  projectId: '',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: '',
  appId: ''
}

export default (config)
(firebaseConfig.js)
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
components
|firebase
||firebase.js
||firebaseConfig.js
|backend
||Dashboard.vue
```

When i load the webpage its just a blank page. Wondering how i can structure this correctly, if anything is unclear just let me know

Comment: Do you see any console error?

Comment: Added the error @ittus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In below line, you have not declared variable `app`, so it's `undefined`

`let db = app.database()`

You can change `firebase.js` to

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import config from './firebaseConfig'

const app = firebase.initializeApp(config)
let db = app.database()

export default db
```

and from your component

```
import db from './firebase.js'
let booksRef = db.ref('books')
...
```